# Drive.Drives.update により共有ドライブの設定を変更したい

Tags: google-apps-script

共有ドライブを自動作成するプログラムを作成しており、用途に応じて「共有ドライブの設定」を変更したいと考えています。
下記の通り、Drive.Drives.update により設定変更を試みましたが、実行結果は失敗でした。
エラーなどは発生せず、ただ単に「共有ドライブの設定」が変更前の状態のままでした。
どのように変更すれば動作するでしょうか？

```
  var updateOptions = {
    "name": "XXXXXX",
    "restrictions": {
      "adminManagedRestrictions": true,
      "domainUsersOnly": true,
      "driveMembersOnly": true,
      "sharingFoldersRequiresOrganizerPermission" : true,
      "copyRequiresWriterPermission" : true
    }
  };

  var updateResources = {
    "useDomainAdminAccess": true
  };
 
  var updateDrive = Drive.Drives.update(updateResources, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", updateOptions);
```

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

[自分が試した限り](https://officeforest.org/wp/2019/12/11/google-apps-script%E3%81%A7%E5%85%B1%E6%9C%89%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%82%92%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/#i-9)ではそもそも、

1. updateResourcesは第三引数です
2. updateResourcesにsupportsAllDrives:trueの設定を入れる必要があります。
3. updateOptionsは第一引数です
4. adminManagedRestrictionsは不要です。

```js
    function sharedDriveSettingChg(){
      let driveId = "ここに共有ドライブの直下のIDを入れる"

      let updateOptions = {
        "restrictions": {
          "domainUsersOnly": false,
          "driveMembersOnly": false,
          "copyRequiresWriterPermission" : false,
          "sharingFoldersRequiresOrganizerPermission":false
        }
      };
    
      let updateResources = {
        "supportsAllDrives":true,
        "useDomainAdminAccess": true
      }; 
    
      
    
      //設定変更実行
      let updateDrive = Drive.Drives.update(
        updateOptions,
        driveId,
        updateResources
      );
    }
```